# How does Nautilus mount webdav without root?

Tags: mount, nautilus, webdav, fuse

Trying to mount a remote `webdav` directory using the command line, *as an ordinary user* without root privileges. It must be possible because Nautilus can do it.

Usual advice is to use `mount -t davfs`, but `mount` requires an entry in `/etc/fstab`.

Also tried `fusedav`, but this fails. Seems to be a common bug:

```
PROPFIND failed: 404 Not Found
```

`wdfs` is not installed.

How does Nautilus do it, and can this be copied on the command line?

Comment: Still waiting eagerly for an answer on this.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are still waiting for an answer, Nautilus seems to use `gio mount` (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5977036 for some more details).

So in case of WeDAV, just use `gio mount davs://...`

Comment: No I gave up and did it another way! This information would have been so useful! Hopefully it will help someone else.

Comment: What is the way that you did it? You should share it here to help others.

Comment: True but that would not have been the answer to the question, by definition. Probably something involving SSHFS.